# google+ api moments.insert 401 Unauthorized with python-requests

Tags: python, google-plus, python-requests

I have successfully inserted a moment with this procedure before and am trying to figure out if the API is currently broken or i'm making a mistake.

I have obtained a valid access_token with request_visible_actions=http://schema.org/AddAction as seen in the partial url below from the auth stage as well as plus.login scope:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&request_visible_actions=http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FAddAction&
```

the request code:

```
import requests
import json
moment = {"type":"http://schema.org/AddAction",
          "object": {"id": "object-id-1",
                     "type":"http://schema.org/AddAction",
                     "name": "The Google+ Platform",
                     "description": "A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!",
                     "image": "https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png"}}

url ='https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault'
params = {'access_token': 'MY_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN'}
r = requests.request("POST",url=url, params=params, json=moment, headers=headers)
print r.url
print r.json()
```

and the result:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
{u'error': {u'code': 401, 
            u'message': 
            u'Unauthorized', 
            u'errors': [{u'domain': u'global', u'message': u'Unauthorized', u'reason': u'unauthorized'}]}}
```

I tried to verify with the tokeninfo endpoint that request_visible_actions are present, but it's not listed there.

confirmed granted scopes:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read'
```

I am able to get moments/vault with the same token so i know it's valid.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Tip: Requests 2.4.2 and up support a `json` keyword argument; you can *omit* the headers and `json.dumps()` call in that case; `r = requests.post(url, json=moment)`

Comment: good tip, i will try that out.

Comment: Lets assume for a moment that `MY_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN` isn't quite URL-safe. Can you try `params={'access_token': MY_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN}` instead of manually adding it to the URL? Remove the `?` at the end of the URL too, of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  no luck, is there any way to verify request_visible_actions?

Comment: I disconnected the app for the user, then reauthenticated and it solved the problem.  Also removed offline access.... Not sure exactly what did it but there is definitely and API bug here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure shown in the question does in fact work as long as `request_visible_actions=space separated list of app activity types` was included when the user makes the first connection to your app and the app activity type you are trying to post was included.  If you want to update the list or add the moment.insert permission after initial authentication, the user must first disconnect the app from their google+ [settings](https://plus.google.com/apps) and reconnect.

It seems this is a bug with google's implementation of `request_visible_actions` and an incremental authorization strategy.

request_visible_actions seems to only be accepted during initial authorization and disregarded after that. This makes incrementally adding this parameter impossible.

Further more, request_visible_actions is not available when calling the tokeninfo endpoint, which leads me to believe that request_visible_actions is somehow dissociated from token auth and merely an attribute assigned to the user's app connection on instantiation.

[Posted to exising moments.instert 401 issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=request_visible_actions&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=878):